# Python protobuf gRPC generates a dependency that doesn't exist

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I'm trying to create a gRPC binding for my python code via:

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I $(pwd)/protos --python_out=./fino/pb2 --grpc_python_out=./fino/pb2 -I=$GOPATH/src -I=$GOPATH/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf $(pwd)/protos/*
```

But the generated file has a dependency that doesn't exist:

```
from github.com.gogo.protobuf.gogoproto import gogo_pb2 as github_dot_com_dot_gogo_dot_protobuf_dot_gogoproto_dot_gogo__pb2
```

which is later used in:

```
DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor.FileDescriptor(
  name='oracle.proto',
  package='oracle',
  syntax='proto2',
  serialized_pb=_b('\n\x0coracle.proto\x12\x06oracle\x1a-github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto\x1a\x1fgoogle/protobuf/timestamp.proto\x1a\x1bgoogle/protobuf/empty.proto\x1a\x0btypes.proto\":\n\x0b\x41\x63\x63ountList\x12+\n\x08\x61\x63\x63ounts\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b...')
  ,
  dependencies=[github_dot_com_dot_gogo_dot_protobuf_dot_gogoproto_dot_gogo__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_timestamp__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,google_dot_protobuf_dot_empty__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,types__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
```

Obviously, I cannot run this code. After trying to delete the non-existent import:

```
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file "oracle.proto":
  oracle.proto: Import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto" has not been loaded.
```

I've tried adding

```
--include_imports --descriptor_set_out=$(pwd)/protos/all.proto
```

but I'm unsure how to add it to my python files. All I want is self-contained description in my python codebase.

EDIT1:
example proto file:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package etcdserverpb;

import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";

option (gogoproto.marshaler_all) = true;
option (gogoproto.sizer_all) = true;
option (gogoproto.unmarshaler_all) = true;
option (gogoproto.goproto_getters_all) = false;

message Request {
    optional uint64 ID         =  1 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional string Method     =  2 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional string Path       =  3 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional string Val        =  4 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Dir        =  5 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional string PrevValue  =  6 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional uint64 PrevIndex  =  7 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   PrevExist  =  8 [(gogoproto.nullable) = true];
    optional int64  Expiration =  9 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Wait       = 10 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional uint64 Since      = 11 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Recursive  = 12 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Sorted     = 13 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Quorum     = 14 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional int64  Time       = 15 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Stream     = 16 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional bool   Refresh    = 17 [(gogoproto.nullable) = true];
}

message Metadata {
    optional uint64 NodeID    = 1 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
    optional uint64 ClusterID = 2 [(gogoproto.nullable) = false];
}
```

This is continuation from https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/issues/376

Comment: It looks odd to me that you have both `-I<whitespace><argument>` and `-I=<argument>` in your command line. It's also not clear to me what purpose `-I=$GOPATH/src -I=$GOPATH/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf` serves. How did those get in there? What do you want them to do? From what example are you working? Also are you able to share your `.proto` content?

Comment: I'm using gogoproto to generate golang code which uses some cool extensions how the generated go code should look like. But it creates issues with python programs and creating python structures. I'd prefer using modern proto3 but above all I'd love working code.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd give it a go. What I did to solve the problem:

1. Download the `github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto` file to your `$(pwd)/protos` folder; name the file `gogo.proto`.
2. Change the include from `import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";` to `import "gogo.proto";`
3. Change the command to explicitly use the proto files: `python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I $(pwd)/protos --python_out=./fino/pb2 --grpc_python_out=./fino/pb2 -I=$GOPATH/src -I=$GOPATH/src/github.com/gogo/protobuf/protobuf $(pwd)/protos/gogo.proto $(pwd)/protos/metadata.proto` (assuming that you named the example proto file as `metadata.proto`).